# What is the Cascade type for create or update in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Suppose `Customer` and `Account` have a one-to-many relationship. Let's say when a new bank account creating customer information also aggregate. 
To accomplish this task the `Account` entity references a `Customer` object as well.

When I persist an `Account` and the `Customer` already exists in the table it needs to be updated or left unchanged. If it doesn't exists a customer record needs to get created. How to do this with help of Cascade types in JPA?
If it's impossible how to escalate this problem?

Account entity:

```
@Entity    
@Table(name = "account")    
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 407923973092266323L;    

    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    @Column(name = "accID")    
    private Integer accountId;        

    @Column(name = "type")    
    private String accType;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
    @JoinColumn(name = "cus_ID")    
    private Customer customer;
            
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)    
    @Column(name = "openDate")    
    private Date createDate;

    // Getters & Setters    
}
```

Customer entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8149369511517077958L;

    @Id    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    @Column(name = "authorID",nullable = false)    
    private Integer cusId;

    @Column(name = "cusName")    
    private String cusName;    

    public Customer(){}

    public Customer(String cusName){this.cusName = cusName}

    // Getter & Setters    
}
```

AccountDAO:

```
@Repository    
public class AccountDAO{    

    @Autowired    
    private AccountRepository accrepo;

    public boolean insertAccount(String accType, String cusName, LocalDate createDate) {            

        try{        

            Date date = Date.from(createDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());        

            Account acc1 = new Account();    
            acc1.setAccType(accType);    
            acc1.setCreateDate(date);    
            acc1.setCustomer(new Customer(cusName));

            accrepo.save(acc1);

            return true;            

        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    }

    return false;    
}
```

Comment: Did you try with @Cascade(CascadeType.UPDATE) annotation?

Comment: I edited your question to make it easier to understand and formatted it for better readability. Please check that I didn't change the meaning.

Comment: Thanks @jens it's great and meaningful more than previous one. It's hard to edit questions by phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the full answer is the JPA specification.

But in principle: yes JPA can handle all the scenarios: A referenced entity being new, unchanged or updated. Although it is easy to run into problems if one doesn't understand the lifecycle of JPA entities.

In any case, it is completely independent of Spring Data and is only defined by JPA. So find a good JPA tutorial and try the different scenarios.

To address the code you posted in your update to the question:

The `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` of the mapping will take care of creating the customer if it isn't present.

If it is present the default approach is to load it first and use that entity. Any changes to it will get automatically persisted.

Comment: Does it mean that require to merge entities (customers) before save the Account? Like check whether customer exit or not before save?

Comment: No, you don't. Spring Data JPA will do that for you. Just give it a try and create new questions when you encounter actual problems.

Comment: Hi, I have updated with code.. 
Lets say customer A need to create 2 accounts. When I invoke insertAccount(...) Twise it's create 2 customers in customer table with same name. I just want to save one customer with 2 accounts..

Comment: each time new customer saving because of setCustomer(new Customer (cusName)); 
Is it the reason? Do I need to search customer before set the customer?

Comment: So if I do as follow:
Peter need to create current and saving accounts. For that i invoked as follow.
`insertAccount("saving","peter","2018-04-12");`
`insertAccount("current","peter","2018-04-12");`

It save 2 records in account table and 2 records in customer table. Why 2 customers? I suppose to save only one customer

Comment: How is JPA supposed to know that these are the same customers?

Comment: Then I need to find first the customer and save after that.

Comment: You don't need to save the customer explicitly. JPA will take care of that.

Comment: Yes...frist check availability of customer and save Account as usually. Is it you mentioned?